# Not able to detect Lenovo K900

Tags: android, eclipse

Has anyone tried developing application using Lenovo K900, I am writing application for my phone (Android 4.2.2) but its not getting detected by eclipse.

Please help

Comment: Is `Developer Options->Android debugging` enabled?

Comment: What OS is the machine with Eclipse?

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede its Windows 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a couple of drivers and the combination seems to do the trick.

I installed the drivers from this post to see the device as a CloverViewPlus device
https://forum.lowyat.net/topic/2918390/+940# (Post #943)

The IntelAndroidDrvSetup1.2.0.exe and iSocUSB-Driver-Setup-1.0.2.exe were needed.

Then I installed the drivers from this post to get Eclipse to recognize the device:
http://singledrivers.blogspot.com/2013/12/lenovo-k900-usb-driver-for-windows.html

It seems that you do not need the MTK driver.
You do seem to need the PDANet Driver.
The ADB driver did not seem to hurt either.

Now Eclipse can see my K900 and download code to it.

Answer (score 0):

Only enabling USB Debugging will not help solve your issue.
You need to install certain drivers in order to make your cell phone visible while running the application.
For now, even I am searching the perfect drivers to install in my system. Will get back to you once I have them. Also, I request you to search as well and revert in case you find success in the same.